# Merging cells using vba

Tags: vba, excel

How can I do the same thing which the code below is doing, except I want to use `cells` instead of `range`? That will allow me to refer to cells in (row,column) format.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").Merge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to return the cell address of the appointed cell(s). Then use the stored string addresses to represent the merge range:

```
Sub merge()

    Dim cell1, cell2 As String

    cell1 = Cells(1, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

    cell2 = Cells(5, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

    ActiveSheet.Range(cell1 + ":" + cell2).merge

End Sub
```

Comment: Rory's solution is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Cells(1, 1).Resize(5).Merge
```

or:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1)).Merge
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a range variable

```
Excel.Range range = ActiveSheet.get_range(ActiveSheet.Cells[1,1], ActiveSheet.Cells[1,4]);
range.Merge();
```